# Changing the way matplotlib reads images

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

I want to build a CNN, and I use matplotlib to read the images(tried to use cv2 but didn't really work well on displaying the images properly and PIL is not working for me for some reason) anyways, I can read the image, but it reads it as Image[height][width][channel]. How can I change it to read it like this:
Image[channel][height][width] so it would be easier for me to convolve it later?
Of course, by saying that I meant without running nested for loops to get every value from every channel and put them in a matrix, I am asking if there's a better way.

I appreciate all the help :)

Comment: There is virtually no reason to switch the order of the axes for your purpose. You can definitely make your convolutions work without resorting to loops---you just need to learn how to deal with broadcasting in numpy :). Also, OpenCV and PIL and virtually any library you will use will expect (h, w, channels) not (channels, h, w). I would recommend with sticking with OpenCV for image reading, and instead change the way you are displaying images to work for you.

Comment: I mean, I could, but just changing the first one to channels is easier because it allows me to irritate through it easily, and Ik it wouldn't accept it that way, that's why I made it a clone of it with a different shape just so I can alter it more easily, and I tried to display the image in CV2 by using cv2.imshow(image) and it did nothing. May I also ask: What exactly do you mean by "broadcasting" in numpy?

Comment: `imshow()` annoyingly doesn't draw the window, you have to use `waitKey()`---see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d2e/tutorial_py_image_display.html). You shouldn't iterate through a numpy array anyways as it's slow; typically in numpy, you use functions from numpy to do the iteration and calculations behind the scenes in C. [Broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in numpy is how you can operate on multiple axes at once, e.g. convolving each channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get where you want using [numpy's `moveaxis()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html#numpy.moveaxis)

```
img = np.zeros((5,6,3))
img.shape
>> (5, 6, 3)
img2 = np.moveaxis(img, -1, 0)
img2.shape
>> (3, 5, 6)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! Altho I need to make another variable to make that since if I want to display the actual image I need to keep it with its original shape, but it does work perfectly, thank you!